# How to replace HTML email links with icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-api, bootstrap-4

Hi I created an email link, upon which a subject, message body and recipients are created and the user only has to click "Send". I followed [this](http://www.zaposphere.com/html-email-links-code/) tutorial and it is working fine.Following is the code.

```
string table = "<tr><td style=\"font-size:12px;\"><td style=\"font-size:12px;\"><a href=\"mailto:recpient@gmail.com?subject=Request to star github repository&body=Hi All, %0D%0DIt is highly appreciated if you could star the following repository.%0D%0DSincerely,%0DHR Admin.\">recpient@gmail.com</a></td>"
```

**Please note that I am returning this as a string and therefore need to escape "**

But now I want to replace the email link with an email icon so that it looks more user friendly.

I added this to the header.

```
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css\">
```

And updated the a tag as follows.

```
<a href=\"mailto:recever@gmail.com?subject=Request to star github repository&body=Hi All, %0D%0DIt is highly appreciated if you could star the following repository.%0D%0DSincerely,%0DHR Admin.\"><i class=\"material-icons\"></i></a>
```

But I am not getting the email icon. When I inspected the html, it has some additional numbers.

```
<i class="m_-6876977088503419915material-icons"></i>
```

When I remove "m_-6876977088503419915", the icon appears. Any reason why this appears and how to correct it? I also tried to define a button class inside a tag but still no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this cdn

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Please replace the code

```
<a href=\"mailto:recever@gmail.com?subject=Request to star github repository&body=Hi All, %0D%0DIt is highly appreciated if you could star the following repository.%0D%0DSincerely,%0DHR Admin.\"><i class=\"material-icons\"></i></a>
```

By

```
<a href="mailto:recever@gmail.com?subject=Request to star github repository&body=Hi All, %0D%0DIt is highly appreciated if you could star the following repository.%0D%0DSincerely,%0DHR Admin."><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
```

Comment: I need tot return this as a string so I need to escape "

Comment: I tried your solution as well but same result: <i class="m_9020520000986433116fa m_9020520000986433116fa-envelope"></i> the issue is with the escaping.

Comment: Are you want to replace the email string to icon? You loaded font awesome so, just set the font awesome icon `<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>` and no need to write `email`

Comment: Yes I removed `email` but still no difference. Refer my previous comment for what I get when I inspect the element.

Comment: I updated my answer. Your font awesome cdn was invalid. please load the cdn that I added and remove the previous one.

Comment: You can see the demo here. just click the run button. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWCEYPY84BMK

Comment: Did everything you mentioned. But did u notice that I want to return this as  a string and therefore need to escape "

Comment: It's not clear but just try this `<a href="mailto:recever@gmail.com?subject=Request to star github repository&body=Hi All, %0D%0DIt is highly appreciated if you could star the following repository.%0D%0DSincerely,%0DHR Admin."><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182071/discussion-between-md-abu-zaman-and-madhuka-wickramapala).